# Trying to remove .php extension using htaccess

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess

Hello guys I am practicing how to change the .php extention in my php pages, no luck yet. I am using WAMP 3.1.0 on a 64bit here the software versions in the WAMP

- Apache Version:2.4.27
- PHP Version:5.6.31    Server Software:Apache/2.4.27 (Win64)
- PHP/5.6.31 - Port defined for Apache: 80

I have the rewrite_module turned on
on the httpd.conf file I have this string "LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so" commented out and changed AllowOverride None to  AllowOverride ALL.

Below is the screenshot of my folder structure

[image]

here is my index.php file screenshot

[image]

here is my htaccss screenshot

[image]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code. Paste your code directly into the question.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this to remove `.php` extensions completely from your file and to avoid infinite loop :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

This code will work in Root/.htaccess, Be sure to change the RewriteBase if you want to place this to a htaccess file in sub directory.

Comment: thanks very much it worked but the code is difficult for me to understand.

Comment: Yes I agree. .htaccess rules are majorly regular expression which works with the parameters and conditions mentioned for request or filenames.